# Pandas return a value of a column by multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this example from [here](https://kanoki.org/2020/01/21/pandas-dataframe-filter-with-multiple-conditions/):

let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['JOHN','ALLEN','BOB','NIKI','CHARLIE','CHANG'],
              'Age':[35,42,63,29,47,51],
              'Salary_in_1000':[100,93,78,120,64,115],
             'FT_Team':['STEELERS','SEAHAWKS','FALCONS','FALCONS','PATRIOTS','STEELERS']})
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['JOHN','ALLEN','BOB','NIKI','CHARLIE','CHANG'],
...               'Age':[35,42,63,29,47,51],
...               'Salary_in_1000':[100,93,78,120,64,115],
...              'FT_Team':['STEELERS','SEAHAWKS','FALCONS','FALCONS','PATRIOTS','STEELERS']})
>>> df
      Name  Age  Salary_in_1000   FT_Team
0     JOHN   35             100  STEELERS
1    ALLEN   42              93  SEAHAWKS
2      BOB   63              78   FALCONS
3     NIKI   29             120   FALCONS
4  CHARLIE   47              64  PATRIOTS
5    CHANG   51             115  STEELERS
```

Let's say I wanna find the salary for Name='John' and Age=35 which is 100. What is the most efficient way to do this query as I am calling this in loop. This is what I am doing which seems that it returns a value of type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>. Thanks!

```
>>> val=df.loc[( (df['Age']== 35) & (df['Name']=="JOHN"))][['Salary_in_1000']]
>>> val
   Salary_in_1000
0             100
>>> type(val)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Why double [[ ]] at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below. This will give you just the value...

```
val=df.loc[( (df['Age']== 35) & (df['Name']=="JOHN"))][['Salary_in_1000']]
```

Comment: sorry.. use the below  val=list(df.loc[( (df['Age']== 35) & (df['Name']=="JOHN"))][['Salary_in_1000']])[0]

Comment: @AvishekPandey this is what it returns:>>> val=list(df.loc[( (df['Age']== 35) & (df['Name']=="JOHN"))][['Salary_in_1000']])[0]
>>> val
'Salary_in_1000'

Answer (score 0):

The syntax here is wrong. Use

```
val=df.loc[(df['Age']== 35) & (df['Name']=="JOHN"), 'Salary_in_1000']
```

or

```
val=df[(df['Age']== 35) & (df['Name']=="JOHN")]['Salary_in_1000']
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it better to use query here for more efficiency? Also, this seems to return a <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>.

Comment: Of course it will return `Series` because there can exist more than one row having these conditions.